# How to see errors of a Testacular/AngularJS test

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I've inherited a AngularJS/Testacular/Jasmine unit test suite and am having difficulty determining how to run a test and see any associated failure messages. That is, I can easily run all the tests, I can do something like `ddescribe` to run one test, and I can see that it fails. But now I have no way to determine why it is failing.

I've installed Firebug and can see console.log statements, but not JavaScript errors (I assume it is a JS error since it just abruptly ends). I also saw the "debug.html" endpoint for Testacular but I have no clue how I'd use it.

How can I see the likely JavaScript errors which are causing my test to fail?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with firebug, but if  you're able to capture a Chrome browser you can open up the developer console (tools -> JavaScript console) and see errors there. You can set a breakpoint when the javascript console is open by putting the line

```
debugger;
```

in your code. The next time your tests are run, Chrome will pause at that line and you can use the console to inspect variables.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Karma version 0.8.4

Not sure whether this is the best way of doing it, but I generally [capture a browser](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/config/browsers.html) while running Karma in the CI mode.

Then I can click on `Debug` button on the open browser window to run Jasmine in a single page mode. That file is hosted at `http://localhost:9876/debug.html` and can be directly accessed, if the `Debug` button is not available/visible.

[image]

Peeking at the console there tells me what errors ail my scripts. I have to do it sometimes since I am using RequireJS and missing dependencies just result in:

> Uncaught Error: Script error
>   http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror

As a side note: consider using [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/install/) to avoid common JS syntax errors.

Comment: I'm not seeing the debug button on the screen, is it limited to specific browsers?

Comment: You should be able to access the page at `http://locahost:your_port/debug.html`, though. Is that also inaccessible? Otherwise, if you are running an older version, can you upgrade?

Comment: I can get to the debug.html page, but it's just a blank page. I'm not sure what to do from there.